# dispatch_group_async time consume strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, performance, grand-central-dispatch

I have UITableView with custom cell. Height of cell is dynamic because of depending on its content. So for fast scrolling, I decided to cache height of cell. I pre-calculate height of all cells with this function:

```
-(void)preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfterThat {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    [MMStopwatchARC start:@"preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0;  i < [self.dataProvider.dataArray count]; i++) {

        dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

            NSString *keyPoitrait = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-p", 0, i];
            NSString *keyLandscape = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-l", 0, i];
            NSNumber* heightCache = [heightCellCache objectForKey:keyPoitrait];

            SETextViewCell *cell = (SETextViewCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView preparedCellForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

            [MMStopwatchARC start:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"preCalculateHeightForCells %@", keyPoitrait]];

            if (heightCache == nil) {


                CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
                CGSize sizeFitContent = [cell.richTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenBound.size.width, 100000)];

                CGFloat height = MAX(self.tableView.rowHeight, sizeFitContent.height);

                [heightCellCache setObject:@(height) forKey:keyPoitrait];

            }

            heightCache = [heightCellCache objectForKey:keyLandscape];

            if (heightCache == nil) {

                SETextViewCell *cell = (SETextViewCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView preparedCellForIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
                CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

                screenBound = CGRectMake(screenBound.origin.x, screenBound.origin.y, screenBound.size.height, screenBound.size.width);

                CGSize sizeFitContent = [cell.richTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenBound.size.width, 100000)];

                CGFloat height = MAX(self.tableView.rowHeight, sizeFitContent.height);
                [heightCellCache setObject:@(height) forKey:keyLandscape];

            }

            [MMStopwatchARC stop:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"preCalculateHeightForCells %@", keyPoitrait]];
        });

    }

    // after all task in group finished
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MMStopwatchARC stop:@"preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter"];

        [weakSelf.tableView setTableFooterView:nil];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];

    });

}
```

I use MMStopwatchARC- stop Watch by Matt Maher  at [here](http://metal-sole.com/2012/01/24/timing-things-in-objective-c-a-stopwatch/) to calculate time consuming on this task. After running, the result in Log is shown below:

```
 -[ViewController preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCells 0-0-p] runtime: [0.053755]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCells 0-1-p] runtime: [0.100539]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCells 0-2-p] runtime: [0.098142]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCells 0-3-p] runtime: [0.062571]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCells 0-4-p] runtime: [0.081574]
 -> Stopwatch: [preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter] runtime: [0.699024]
```

The problem is why **Time-preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter is so much greater than preCalculateHeightForCells**?

And I add group to global queue so the tasks must run concurrent but the log so that task (calculate cell for each height) run in sequence (just like serial queue).

Comment: you do not need to _pre-calculate_ the height of the cells, the `UITableView` is intelligent enough to ask the height of the cells which are actually appears on the screen. those amount of calculation – according to your code – would be much faster than preparing all cells, which may not appear on the screen at all. I see a little an little own-goal in you concept here.

Comment: My UItablview cell is custom cell with SECoreTextView (from Github). This cell will render NSAttributedString with different font, size, color and also images. When UITableView ask height for certain cell, The cell must re-calculate the height with high consume CPU (especially for old device like iphone 3GS) --> so it make "lag". I do this method to get height of cell in background thread while show loading indicator in UI. After pre_calculate, the table scroll smoothy because the height of cell is already calculated and cached.

Comment: after the content of the `UITableView` is loaded, usually the very next appearing cell's height will be requested from the `UITableView`. that means you need to calculate the height only for _one_ cells before that particular cell appears. so, why would pre-calculating _all_ cell's height be faster than calculating only _one_ cell's details? I'm sure you are overcomplicate a very simple issue here, and you may not be familiar with the concept of the `UITableView`, perhaps?

Comment: I've created a complex spreadsheet application for iPad2, each row has multiple cells in the app with `NSAttributedString` objects which calculated dynamically, and there was zero performance issue...

Comment: I think you have no problem because Ipad 2 had more powerful CPU than Iphone 3GS. The calculate height for a cell will be not a problem with CPU IPad but Iphone 3GS. Do you have test you app or some thing similar that in old device link Iphone 3GS?

Comment: okay, I'm not here to arguing with your ideas, but you have to see how inefficient to _load_ a cell in to the memory(!) and _calculate_ its height(!), and doing to for each cell – even if the actual cell may not appear at all – guess how inefficient this idea in case of `10.000` cells.

Comment: You right. I should re-design my solution but back to origin problem that I want to ask. Do you have any idea why Time-preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter is so much greater than preCalculateHeightForCells?. It just my curious. Thank for your opinion:D

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what that 3rd party stuff does, I'm not using unofficial 3rd party stuff in my apps. :) they are mostly unreliable, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you very much @holex ! Even though we have some different opinion but I realy appreciate your help!

Comment: we always can learn something from each other. :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between total time of preCalculateHeightForCells runtime (0.396581s) and preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter runtime (0.699024s) might be came from the main queue execution timing.

You are using global queue for each preCalculateHeightForCells.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    ...
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
```

And the notification after all tasks done is executed on the main queue (the main thread).

```
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

The task on the main queue will be scheduled on the next runloop execution timing. But I'm not sure why the delay was so long (0.699024s-0.396581s=0.302443s). Usually the delay is 1/60s (0.0167s) or less. The app was so busy at that time? dispatch_group_notify with global queue might get better result if global queues are available to execute the task.

```
// after all task in group finished
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    [MMStopwatchARC stop:@"preCalculateHeightForCellsAndReloadTableAfter"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf.tableView setTableFooterView:nil];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```